# Scrapy taking text from a webpage

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to make a scrapy spider file that lifts the main block of text off of a webpage. I have succeeded in using the scapy tutorial but when I come to use my own website I cannot get it to work. I think it may have something to do with my xpaths but I do not have enough knowledge about that to fix it.

Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.inkstudents.co.uk/"]
    start_urls = [
'http://www.inkstudents.co.uk/article/is-venice-sinking', 
'http://www.inkstudents.co.uk/article/what-do-romeo-and-juliet-and-the-eurozone-have-in-common'
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = DmozItem()
        #item['title'] = sel.xpath('//body/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="mainCont"]/div[3]/div[2]').extract()
        #item['desc'] = sel.xpath('/html').extract()
        yield item
```

I do also have a items.py file.

here is the log:

```
2015-11-17 21:09:45 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: Tutorial)
2015-11-17 21:09:45 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl,     http11
2015-11-17 21:09:45 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings:   {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Tutorial.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',     'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Tutorial.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'test4.json', 'BOT_NAME':    'Tutorial'}
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider,   FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:   HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware,    RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware,   HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware,      ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:   HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware,    UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET   http://www.inkstudents.co.uk/article/what-do-romeo-and-juliet-and-the-  eurozone-have-in-common> (referer: None)
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET   http://www.inkstudents.co.uk/article/is-venice-sinking> (referer: None)
2015-11-17 21:09:46 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-11-17 21:09:47 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 527,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 12034,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 21, 9, 46, 999995),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 21, 9, 46, 430059)}
2015-11-17 21:09:47 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: can you share the logs? for what I see, you should only specify `['inkstudents.co.uk']` in `allowed_domains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is a problem with your xpath.

By just interacting with response, I'm able to get all of the content out of `articleContent` on the website.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="articleContent"]/p/text()'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['link'] = sel
        yield item
```

Don't know if this is exactly what you want, but it should give you a good start for the xpath.

Hope this helps!

NOTE: I put the text in the link item of DmozItem because that's what you have in the example, but it is NOT a link

Comment: Hi I changed my code to use that instead and now I get Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or none, got 'Selector'. How do I get rid of that? Thanks

Comment: I tried something else, but I'm not sure how you're actually using the code. the xpath that I put in there is correct for your sites though